# Create multiple tables with same domain in jpaRepository

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I have one `@Table` domain and want to create multiple tables using that. How can I do it with JPARepository.

```
@Table
public class structure implements Serializable{
  ...
}
```

I want to create a lot of tables with different names and same structure in run time and save records to them.

How can I do this with JPARepository?

Comment: If it is same multiple times, please use  the same.

Comment: @ꜱᴜʀᴇꜱʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ But i want 15 tables. Do you mean i create 15 same domain files in my project? with 15 JPARepository?

Comment: Yup. That is how it should be

Comment: But that's not dynamic. It's 100% manually and is not clear code.

Comment: If that is not dynamic, can you build your whole project on 1 database table please ? why you have 15 tables ?

Comment: Because i'm working on large date and if i insert all of them in one table my query performance is low.

Comment: I want to categorize them in different tables.

Comment: Exactly. If you create a single repository, you end up in castings and if else's

Comment: How can i do that? can you explain more? i can't understand.

Comment: That's not possible with JPA

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Which way do you offer?

Comment: I didn't fully understand your use case and what you want to achieve. Can you please explain it in more detail?

Comment: Sure. suppose i have a lot of records of USER. User in different types for example student, driver and ... . All of users have same structure but i wand divide them to multiple tables by multiple names. how can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating JPA mapped classes dynamically is not possible. But there are possibles to minimize the code you have to write.

**MappedSuperClass**

Create one class annotated with [`MappedSuperclass`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/MappedSuperclass.html) and let all other classes inherit from it. This way the actual mapped classes contain very little code.

**Inheritance**
You mentioned in the comments that your classes are *different types*. This suggests that maybe inheritance with a table per class is the correct way to go.

Again create a superclass with all your proper classes to inherit from, but this time annotate them as with [`@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)`](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/complete-guide-inheritance-strategies-jpa-hibernate/)

**Partitioning**

You write in the comments

> Because I'm working on a large amount of data and if I insert all of them in one table my query performance is low.

Which makes me think you might be approaching this on the wrong level and you should really look into partitioning. The availability of this and how it exactly works depends on the database you use. [Therefore I just leave a link to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(database)).